# doctrine2 increases my primary key when it fails to insert a record

Tags: php, postgresql, symfony, doctrine-orm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is there a way to avoid calling nextval() if the insert fails in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2036571/is-there-a-way-to-avoid-calling-nextval-if-the-insert-fails-in-postgresql)
>   [Rails - Postgres does not re-use deleted ids but MySql does?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9984196/rails-postgres-does-not-re-use-deleted-ids-but-mysql-does)

I have very simple database with **PostgreSQL 9.2.1**. When i insert something with **Doctrine2** by using this method:

```
$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

If I get an error

> -means record **NOT** inserted-

it still adds `1` to my primary key. So if i refresh the page `50` times, it says auto increment value is set to `50`. How can I prevent this? If record not insterted than why primary key increases. This is very critical because it uses indexes for nothing and the number keep going bigger.

I have no idea what it came from and why, so, i did not tried anything. Very stuck at this point.

Comment: See this earlier answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9985219/398670

Comment: Oh, i was thinking it was came from doctrine. This is my first discover of this issue. I never see such this thing before. Sorry guys. I accept an answer and yes this question is duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doctrine2 uses transactions to complete it's tasks.

Each time a Doctrine flushes its changes to the database, it opens a transaction, each record is prepared and then the commit will action the changes all at once.

During this process, the records that require an `auto_increment` ID are assigned. If the record then fails during the commit phase, the records aren't added, but the auto increment has issued that ID.

You can read more about Transactions here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-transactions.html

Note: This is also the same for MySQL and I'm sure the same for many other RDBMS.

Comment: It's actually the nature of sequence operation under concurrency more than the presence of transactional context that's key here. Even without transactions, it would be undesirable to reset a sequence's last value when an insert fails as another concurrent activity may have already advanced it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to avoid the behaviour you observe without incurring substantial performance penalty or incorrect concurrent operation.

[Auto-incrementing fields](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) are implemented by tying the field to a [sequence](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createsequence.html) via `default nextval('seqeunce_name')`.

Sequences are designed to guarantee that they always emit a unique value even under concurrent operation. They have no guarantee that they always emit sequential values. When `nextval()` is called as you attempt to insert a row, the value is emitted and will never be emitted again by the sequence unless you manually reset the sequence using [`setval()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html).

Since incrementing a sequence safely necessarily incurs lock overhead, under highly concurrent operations some dbms systems will cache a set of sequence values for each transaction or session to avoid excessive locking -- this further exacerbates the skipped sequence value problem.  In postgres, such caching of values is controlled via the `CACHE cache` clause of the sequence creation.